# Introductory book on philosophy of logic?

Tags: logic, reference-request, philosophy-of-logic

I know that there are quite a few questions like this here already, but I haven't yet found an answer that would satisfy me.

I'm looking for an introductory logic book. My main goal is to work towards understanding philosophy of logic (also philosophical logic and mathematical logic, but philosophy of logic is my main goal). I'm self-studying, so a book with exercises and answers to them would be great.

I've come across the following, seemingly interesting books:
The Logical Basis of Metaphysics by Dummett, and
The Concept of Logical Consequence by McKeon,
but for me to be able to read these, I need to study some basic logic and philosophy first. So any book recommendations that would help me achieve my goal would be really helpful!

Edit: For example, what books should I read/study before trying to read An Introduction to Philosophical Logic by Grayling? How hard to read are books like On The Philosophy of Logic by Fisher, and Thinking About Logic by Read? Fisher's book seems like it could be understood without that much experience on the subject.

Answer (score 4):

See :

- W.V.Quine, [Philosophy of Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=GxlUEyI-6JoC&printsec=frontcover) (2nd ed 2009)
- Hilary Putnam, [Philosophy of Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=QxpIAwAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover) (1971)
- John Burgess, [Philosophical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=k32w3_wjBoYC&printsec=frontcover) (2009)

Comment: Can these be read without much prior understaning of logic? (I'm familiar with the basics: truth tables, quantifiers, the basic symbols (and, or etc...)...)

Comment: @user265554 - they are not (for the most part) "technically" complex... this does not mean that they are "easy" to read.

Comment: Hard to read is not really an issue. Problems emerge if the text presupposes a lot of prior knowledge on the subject.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at Irving M. Copi's *Symbolic Logic*, though I do not know whether it has been updated since the fifth edition in 1979.

Answer (score 0):

try Ted Sider's, Logic for Philosophy (http://tedsider.org/books/lfp.html)

Comment: Link only answers loose value if the link changes, can you summarize?