# What is the most famous book on philosophical logic?

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-logic

I'm interested in philosophical logic and finding references. I know that there are plenty of reference request of philosophical logic. But it seems to me that most of them are about symbolic logic, baby logic or modal logic. But there is not enough about philosophy of logic.

My university course on *philosophy of logic* uses A.C. Grayling's *An introduction to philosophical Logic*. And I would like to know what is the most famous book in this area.

Comment: See this [post](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/30436/introductory-book-on-philosophy-of-logic).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I've already seen that post. But it's about preliminary one. It's not what I want

Comment: Aristotle's formalization of logic and the syllogism was by far the most influential and "famous" work of its kind for nearly 2000 years. It was considered by many to be a virtually "closed topic" nearly until the time of Boole, say, though there was significant medieval critique and advancement both in the Christian and Islamic schools.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the most **famous** book on philosophical logic?

Leaving aside the issue of the definition of 'philosophical logic', I think that the most famous book about it is the

[Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tractatus_Logico-Philosophicus)

of Wittgenstein. A touch-stone for Analytic philosophers and other kinds of pony-tailed pedants.

Comment: And leaving aside Aristotle, the dominant and best-known work in logic for nearly 2000 years. Ah, how quickly we moderns forget...

Comment: @NelsonAlexander And its not a particularly forgettable book... The 2nd line we read is *"The world is the totality of facts, not of things."*. Monstrous!

Comment: No, I meant Aristotle's logic is the "dominant and best-known"...Tractatus is a work of poetry.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend two books.  (1) An introduction to logic, by H.W.B. Joseph http://www.worldcat.org/title/introduction-to-logic-by-hwb-joseph/oclc/373124 (2) Two Logics: The Conflict between Classical and Neo-Analytic Philosophy by Henry B. Veatch [http://www.amazon.com/Two-Logics-Classical-Neo-Analytic-Philosophy/dp/B0006BUTI6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006BUTI6)

Comment: Why these books over others?